# Newtonsoft json deserialization - key as property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a json file :

```
...
    "Key1": {
        "Base": 123,
        "Max": 1234
    },
    "Key2": {
        "Base": 123,
        "Max": 1234
    },
    "Key3": {
        "Base": 123,
        "Max": 1234
    },
...
```

I need to deserialize it into an object with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(__json);`

But I need to use the keys (Key1, Key2, Key3,...) as a property of my deserialized object.
Unfortunately, I can't use an alternate deserialization method and I can't modify the json format.

My object is like that

```
public class Item {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Base { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

My Id's should be "Key1", "Key2, ...

is it possible?

Comment: why not a list of a custom `Key` class with `Base` and `Max` properties? you can then enumerate through each `Key`'s properties using a loop

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know, the only way to do this is with a custom reflection approach. That's not too bad at all, but I don't think there's anything built-in that will do it.

Comment: The real object is more complex and have some OnDeserialization attributes on sub-objects and the key (an enum) is used to compute some data.
I use a big Framework that deserialize from automatically generated files and I can't change the deserialization process or the json.
but I can add JsonConverter, ContractResolver, CustomConverter, attribute or any other thing like that, but I can only update my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom `Key` class:

```
public class Key {
    public int Base { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

Then store each item in the JSON result in a `Dictionary` where it's key is the key name and it's value is a `Key` item:

```
var keyCollection = new Dictionary<string, Key>();

//you can then do stuff such as:
var maxOfKeyOne = keyCollection["Key1"].Max; 
var baseOfKeyTwo = keyCollection["Key2"].Base;
```

Comment: Finally I used a dictionary and built my sub-objects with it with the OnDeserialized method, thanks.

Comment: @Demonia could you share what you did here?