# JSON DeserializeObject to Model without Key Name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I currently have JSON coming in as follows:

```
{"36879":[{"min_qty":1,"discount_type":"%","csp_price":10}],"57950":[{"min_qty":1,"discount_type":"flat","csp_price":650}]}
```

This contains a list of the following records

**ProductId**
MinQty
DiscountType
Price

I need to deserialize this into the following model:

```
public class CustomerSpecificPricing
    {
        string productId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<CustomerSpecificPricingDetail> CustomerSpecificPricingDetails { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomerSpecificPricingDetail
    {
        public string min_qty { get; set; }
        public string discount_type { get; set; }
        public string csp_price { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is that the "productId" of each record is missing the key name.

If I run my JSON through J2C, I get the following:

```
public class 36879    {
    public int min_qty { get; set; } 
    public string discount_type { get; set; } 
    public int csp_price { get; set; } 
}

public class 57950    {
    public int min_qty { get; set; } 
    public string discount_type { get; set; } 
    public int csp_price { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public List<_36879> _36879 { get; set; } 
    public List<_57950> _57950 { get; set; } 
}
```

Which is obviously incorrect.

How would I deserialize my object correctly?

Comment: use a `Dictionary<string,YourClass>`

Comment: var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, CustomerSpecificPricing>>(rules);

I get the following error: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'app.debug+CustomerSpecificPricing' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728161/newtonsoft-json-deserialization-key-as-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to deserialize it into a dictionary first and then map it into the format you require after. Something like this should work:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<CustomerSpecificPricingDetail>>>();

var result = dict.Select(kvp => new CustomerSpecificPricing { ProductId = Int32.Parse(kvp.Key), CustomerSpecificPricingDetails = kvp.Value });
```

Id also recommend you follow the conventional standards of naming. In this case properties in classes should be PascalCase,

e.g. your classes now become:

```
public class CustomerSpecificPricing
{
   [JsonProperty("productId ")]
   public string ProductId { get; set; }
   public virtual List<CustomerSpecificPricingDetail> CustomerSpecificPricingDetails { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomerSpecificPricingDetail
{
   [JsonProperty("min_qty")]
   public string MinQty { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("discount_type ")]
   public string DiscountType { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("csp_price ")]
   public string CspPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the `Int32.Parse(kvp.Key)` is not safe and you would probably want to add appropriate handling for that failing.

Comment: Perfect, Matt. You have some trailing spaces in the JsonProperty names in the class.